# Zip all uncompressed file in a folder in one line

Tags: linux, bash, compression

I have a lot of text files that I want to compress. Each file must be compressed separately. But some of them are already compressed.

How do I, in one line, compress all files that end with `.txt` by appending `.zip` to their name?

I know in Bash I can, but I don't know how.

- `find /path/to/files -name "*.txt"` will list me those files
- `zip fname.txt.zip fname.txt` will compress the file
- `rm fname.txt` will remove the original file

How do I pipe those in one line? I have little understanding of `xargs` I frequently see in these cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it can be done with a piped command, find is able to do it on its own:

```
find /path/to/files -name '*.txt' -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' ';' -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

As you may guess -exec runs the command that is terminated by a semicolon (which is hidden from the shell using quotes or a backslash) and {} means the name of currently found and handled file (and it's also hidden from the shell).

Answer (score 0):

Took a breath and... two commands

- `find . | grep -i '\.txt$' | xargs -I {} zip {}.zip {}`
- `find . | grep -i '\.txt$' | xargs -I {} rm {}`